# PCI Express X1 TV Tuners Card What I need to Get it working

Tags: motherboard, tuner-card, pci-express

Okay I'm planning to get this [Barebones](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=5263757&Sku=B69-0125) from TigerDirect

It's cheap and decent. But the downside is that the motherboard only has 1 PCIx16 which I need for my Video Card, and one PCI express which I need for my Wifi, and only left with the tiny PCI x1 slot available. I'm thinking to get a TV turner for that space.

Wondering which and what kind TV tuner can I get out from the PCI ex1

also What do I need to be able to watch TV from the TV Turner.

Do I need to have to have my cable TV subscription in order to watch TV ? What channel will I get from there ? Same as what I get from the big screen TV or different?

I'm in Canada, will I be able to watch some US Channel from this TV Turner?

New to all those TV Tuners stuff. Any suggestions and ideas?

Answer (score 2):

TV Tuners are just a kind of PROPER receivers of TV signals through cable/wireless medium.
If you have a wired connection to your TV right now, you just need to plug that wire into the TVTuner slot of PC. You also need a software to view the actual TV. Most cases, TVTuner bundles appropriate software with them. I own a Pinnacle PCTV Analog which comes with Pinnacle media center.

TVTuners scan as good as TV for identifying channels (direct signals with no settop box), but in some cases(rare) it can miss some of channels. If you have a SetTop box, then most probably receiving will be done by that unit itself and you use TV just for displaying channels. In this case, if you connect it to PC TVTuner you wont lose any channels!

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TV_tuner_card) is a good starting info for TVTuners.

Comment: thansk for the reply, my question is will be able to watch TV if I don't have subscription from the TV cable company ? and What will the TV channel depend on my local provider ?

Comment: Wihtout cable company subscription, as far as i know you cannot watch TV.

Comment: thanks, I have the basic channel, is there anyway to watch the "premium channel" on the TV tuner without paying for it?

Comment: TV Tuners are just a way of watching your TV in PC... its technical... paying for it and watching is how the cable business system works.. So if you have not paid, you cannot watch it... Whatever channels you are subscribed for you will get that in PC... though i did not understand the concept of basic and premium channels (i am from different part of the world but idea is same here also)

Comment: @aviator  Not quite true.  If you have digital tuner card you can connect an antenna and receive DTV broadcasts.  Likewise if you're in an area that has analog stations still broadcasting (low power stations in the US are still allowed to broadcast) you can pick them up as well.

Comment: @Dan: Oh yeah!!I almost forgot. we had one a long time back also. thanks for pointing out